# There is spinner coming when I click on Drop-down button in p-autocomplete (prime-ng)

Tags: javascript, angular, primeng-dropdowns

I have a drop down, I used primeng p-autocomplete  when I am clicking on drop down button it is working fine and when I click on the second time there is spinner coming and nothing happens. there is no console error also.

I checked using many sites but i didn't found any answer. I tried to implement from many ways but it is giving me same error.

```
 <p-autoComplete [(ngModel)]="brokerName" [suggestions]="brokerList" 
   (completeMethod)="filterBrands($event)" [size]="12" [minLength]="3" field="label" (onselect)="getHouseBrokers($event)"
 inputStyleClass="txt-box" placeholder="Qualbe Broker List" [dropdown]="true" [forceSelection]="true">
                </p-autoComplete>
```

This code i working if i Click only once or i typed something it is giving me proper output but when i click twice on drop down button spinner come and nothing happens.

here is my drop down box :

[image]

[image]

here is when i clicked on drop down button twice a spinner come and it started spinning :

[image]

Comment: It seems to be a feature of primeng [autocomplete](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/src/app/components/autocomplete/autocomplete.ts#L368). When you search, it triggers loading and after the suggestions are handled, the loading stops.

Comment: @KiraAG But I am not searching anything . I am just clicking on that drop down button twice

Comment: @Debashishdwivedi whe you click second time, is the dropdown populated?